# EditText box contents into ListView on Android after clicking Button

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Would like to see if someone can help me on figuring out how to add the contents of a EditText box into a ListView list on Android. I have a project I'm working on that, uses Barcode Scanner to scan a barcode, and return the results into the EditText box.

I'm now attempting to code the contents of the EditText box with the use of a button to add the contents in the list either within that activity or on another one. I've looked at the simple note list example and a couple of other examples, however, when I try and implement some of the same concepts, I get no where or I think I get somewhere, but the code does nothing. I'm sorry it's late.. been up all night trying to figure this out...
Any help, advice, is greatly and always appreciated...

```
package com.terrellmcqueen.databaseproject474;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final int REQUEST_BARCODE = 0;
    private TextView mBarcodeEdit;
    private TextView mScanButton;

    // private fields omitted

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mBarcodeEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
        mScanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
        mScanButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.scanButton:
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "SCAN_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_BARCODE);
                break;
        }
     }

     public void onClick1(View v) {
         switch (v.getId()) {
             case R.id.btnSimple:    
                 ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
                 final EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);        
                 final ArrayList<String> noteList = new ArrayList<String>();
                 final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

                 // binding an array of Strings 
                 aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,noteList);

                 // here we set the adapter, this turns it on
                 myListView.setAdapter(aa);

                 // here is the button
                 // Button btnSimple = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSimple);

                 //  String barcode = mBarcodeEdit.getText().toString();

                 //  String title = mTitleEdit.getText().toString();
                 //  String price = mPriceEdit.getText().toString();
            }
      }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_BARCODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String barcode = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                mBarcodeEdit.setText(barcode);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the code little bit and it's working according to your requirement please look at the same

```
package com.barcode;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BarcodeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final int REQUEST_BARCODE = 0;
    private TextView mBarcodeEdit;
    private Button mScanButton;
    private Button mAddButton;

    // private fields omitted

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mBarcodeEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        mScanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        mScanButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mAddButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "SCAN_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_BARCODE);
            break;
        case R.id.add:
            ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            final EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            final ArrayList<String> noteList = new ArrayList<String>();
            noteList.add(myEditText.getText().toString());
            final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

            // binding an array of Strings
            aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, noteList);

            // here we set the adapter, this turns it on
            myListView.setAdapter(aa);
            break;
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_BARCODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String barcode = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                mBarcodeEdit.setText(barcode);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! worked like a charm... another quick question though, right now the code scans, returns a barcode, and I'm able to click the add button to add to list, however, if I (click AddButton) or (scan) to add another item, it just replaces the previous item that was scanned... how do I get it where the code has a list of items scanned... right now it's just one... I'm still working on it now to see what I'm not doing to prevent this from happening...again thanks...

Comment: // here we set the adapter, this turns it on
            myListView.setAdapter(aa);
         
            // add the note
            noteList.add(0,myEditText.getText().toString());
            
            // update the view
      aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
      
      //erase the text so we can add another note
      myEditText.setText("");

Comment: Never mind the last comment... I got it! Thanks so much for your feedback. Now I'm pushing on to the next phase within my app...

Comment: Please accept the ans. there will be tick mark beside the vote. so we can conclude the question

Answer (score 1):

In the button click event, add the editText's text to the list used to populate the ListView and call the notifyDataSetChanged() of your ArrayAdapter. Hope that would work.

```
noteList.add(mBarcodeEdit.getText());
aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
```